# How to Filter by sportsname

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am developing an App where I have to filter by sportsname. I am
using Node.js and MongoDB in the Backend.

Here is my Code:-

```
router.route('/user/:_id/explore/:sportsname')

.get(function(req, res, next){
        var query = Host.find();

        if(req.query.sportsname){
                query.where({sportsname:req.query.sportsname});
        }

        query.exec(function(err,sportsname){
                if(err)
                        return next(err);
                res.json(sportsname);
                console.log(sportsname);
        })
});
```

Here is the document. I want to search the users by sportsname

```
[  
   {  
      "_id":"5460e2af4ee5216f17000061",
      "maxplayer":"1",
      "minplayer":"11",
      "date":"10 August 2014",
      "venue":"google",
      "time":"Afternoon",
      "sportsname":"Lawn Tennis",
      "__v":0
   },
   {  
      "_id":"5460ff1b4ee5216f17000065",
      "maxplayer":"0",
      "minplayer":"9",
      "date":"10 October 2014",
      "venue":"google",
      "time":"Early Morning",
      "sportsname":"Cricket",
      "__v":0
   },
   {  
      "_id":"5461a4014ee5216f17000089",
      "maxplayer":"4",
      "minplayer":"29",
      "date":"13 December 2014",
      "venue":"google",
      "time":"Afternoon",
      "sportsname":"Lawn Tennis",
      "__v":0
   }
]
```

When I am running on that time it is not filtering.

Comment: What do your documents look like? Without that no-one has any idea how to answer. Also `req.params.sportsname`. Well should be as "query" should be an agument in the url

Comment: `req.query.sportsname` should be `req.params.sportsname`

Comment: Ok Thanks. Let me replace it and run it...

Comment: @Neil Lunn: Thanks. If you dont mind then can you tell me in brief.

Comment: You need to use the **edit** link on your question. Don't try and post additional information as a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you're using `req.query.sportsname`

This is for getting the parameter from the query string.

As others have mentioned in the comments, you should use `req.params.sportsname`
An alternative would be to use `req.param('sportsname')

This would look up the parameter in the following order:

- req.params
- req.body
- req.query

However, this is a minor point

One issue I see is you have spaces / capitalisation in your `sportsname` in your

```
"sportsname":"Lawn Tennis",
```

but you're passing these in via the URL params  - "/user/id/explore/Lawn Tennis" isn't valid a valid url, and would be encoded to "Lawn%20Tennis"

One way round this is to use `decodeURIComponent` -

So, try changing your query to:

```
query.where({sportsname:decodeURIComponent(req.params.sportsname)});
```

(note my use of `req.params` rather than `req.query`)

Another way would be to store an additional element in your document -
Something like sportsnameslug - 
Which you would create at the time of saving the document 
(Converting "Lawn Tennis" to "lawn-tennis" for example)

Then querying on that

Comment: Thanks...But still it is showing the same as it was before. Showing the full documents. Its not filtering.

Comment: the query isn't being applied - do a console.log(req.params. sportsname') and see what it is

Comment: ...did you change the req.query.sportsname to req.params.sportsname

Comment: ALex one question how to list all the records that is filtered by sportsname

Comment: When I am running the app on that time it is showing the name of the sports but I am not getting the full record...